# Caching parallel request in Spring Webflux Mono

Tags: caching, mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

We are using spring webflux (project reactor), as part of the requirement we need to call one API from our server.

For the API call, we need to cache the response. So we are using `Mono.cache` operator.

It caches the response `Mono<ResponseDto>` and the next time the same API call happens, it will get it from the cache. Following is example implementation

```java
public Mono<ResponseDto> getResponse() {
    if (res == null) {
      res =
          fetchResponse()
              .onErrorMap(Exception.class, (error) -> new CustomException())
              .cache(
                  r -> Duration.ofSeconds(r.expiresIn()),
                  error -> Duration.ZERO,
                  () -> Duration.ZERO);
    }
    return res;
  }
```

The problem is if the server calls the same API call twice ( for example `Mono.zip`) at the same time, then the response is not cached and we actually call it twice.

Is there any out of box solution available to this problem? Instead of caching the Response, can we cache the Mono itself so that both requests subscribe to the same Mono hence both are executed after a Single API call response?

It should also work with sequential execution too - I am afraid that if we cache the Mono then once the request is completed, the subscription is over and no other process can subscribe to it.

[image: Cases]

Comment: `Is there a solution to this problem?` well yes, implement a cache, use springs cachable annotation and pick a underlying cache solution, like google guava, redis, or of you need a distributed cache solution hazelcast. Webflux/Rector is not a cache solution

Comment: @Toerktumlare added more info - the focus is on "out of box solution". We can add custom coding to solve the problem, however if there is any inbuilt method then best.

Comment: Then no, there is no global caching solution in a reactive library. For that you use a global caching solution.

Comment: @Akshay Are there any prerequisites for `cache()` method to work?
I have practically same code, but `fetchResponse()` is called every time, so cache is not used at all.

Comment: I am not sure about the answer, could you give us the code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project Reactor provides a cache utility CacheMono that is non-blocking but can stampede.

AsyncCache will be better integration, for the first lookup with key "K" will result in a cache miss, it will return a CompletableFuture of the API call and for the second lookup with the same key "K" will get the same CompletableFuture object.

The returned future object can be converted to/from Mono with `Mono.fromFuture()`

```
 public Mono<ResponseData> lookupAndWrite(AsyncCache<String, ResponseData> cache, String key) {
return Mono.defer(
    () ->
        Mono.fromFuture(
            cache.get(
                key,
                (searchKey, executor) -> {
                  CompletableFuture<ResponseData> future = callAPI(searchKey).toFuture();
                  return future.whenComplete(
                      (r, t) -> {
                        if (t != null) {
                          cache.synchronous().invalidate(key);
                        }
                      });
                })));}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the `Mono` in the constructor (assuming it doesn't depend on any request time parameter). Using `cache` operator will prevent multiple subscriptions to the source.

```java
class MyService {
    private final Mono<ResponseBodyDto> response;

    public MyService() {
        response = fetchResponse()
            .onErrorMap(Exception.class, (error) -> new CustomException())
            .cache(
                r -> Duration.ofSeconds(r.expiresIn()),
                error -> Duration.ZERO,
                () -> Duration.ZERO);
    }

    public Mono<ResponseDto> getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
}
```

If there is a dependency on request time parameters, you should consider some custom caching solution.

Comment: We cannot, if we could then better solution is to prefetch the data and catch the result!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CacheMono` from `io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-extra` to wrap non-reactive cache implementation like Guava Cache or simple `ConcurrentHashMap`. It doesn't provide an "exactly-once" guarantee and parallel requests could result in cache misses, but in many scenarios, it should not be an issue.

Here is an example with Guava Cache

```
public class GlobalSettingsCache {
    private final GlobalSettingsClient globalSettingsClient;
    private final Cache<String, GlobalSettings> cache;

    public GlobalSettingsCache(GlobalSettingsClient globalSettingsClient, Duration cacheTtl) {
        this.globalSettingsClient = globalSettingsClient;
        this.cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(cacheTtl)
                .build();
    }

    public Mono<GlobalSettings> get(String tenant) {
        return CacheMono.lookup(key -> Mono.justOrEmpty(cache.getIfPresent(key)).map(Signal::next), tenant)
                .onCacheMissResume(() -> fetchGlobalSettings(tenant))
                .andWriteWith((key, signal) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() ->
                        Optional.ofNullable(signal.get())
                                .ifPresent(value -> cache.put(key, value))));
    }

    private Mono<GlobalSettings> fetchGlobalSettings(String tenant) {
        return globalSettingsClient.getGlobalSettings(tenant);
    }
}
```